# How to add grand total of percentage values in Tableau table?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have to create a table in Tableau with percentage values. These are calculated fields with numerator x and denominator y. I want to add grand total at the bottom of each column. If I use Total function from Tableau it will add percentage values from all the rows. But the grand total value I want is sum(x)/sum(y) for each column. Can anyone suggest how I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

{ fixed: sum([X]) } / { fixed: sum( [Y] ) }